# JSON <html> Error

Tags: java, php, android, json

Trying to input some data into the server, but my JSON doesn't seem to be working. The values don't update in the server, and in the Eclipse console, it returns "`

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

It seems like it isn't inputting the data, but is trying to read directly from the code, which is html, instead of the `"success":1` that I want. When I do it from the web browser, it works fine, which shows it is a JSON issue.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Time Update</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';


$dbuser = 'casaange_testapp';
$dbpass = 'testapp1';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('casaange_volunteertest');
$email= $_POST['email'];
$time= $_POST['time'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET time= '$time' WHERE email = '$email'";



$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}

if($retval){
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Update successful!";
die(json_encode($response));
}

//echo '{"success":1, "message":"Time added!"}';
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Email:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Time:</td>
<td><input name="time" type="text" id="time"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Code:

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Info.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        //              String userName;
        //              String userEmail;
        //              double userTime;
        //              String userSchool;
        //String time = Double.parseDouble(TotalHours.toString());
        //              double HoursValue = 0;
        //              double MinuteValue = 0;
        //              double TotalTime;
        //              String TotalTimeString;
        //          try{
        //              HoursValue = Double.parseDouble(HoursEditText.getText().toString());
        //          }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        //              HoursEditText.setText("0");
        //          }try{
        //              MinuteValue = Double.parseDouble(MinutesEditText.getText().toString());
        //          }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        //              MinutesEditText.setText("0");
        //          }       
        //              
        //              TotalTime = (HoursValue + (MinuteValue/60)) + Global.userTime;
        //              System.out.println(TotalTime);
        //              TotalTimeString = String.valueOf(TotalTime);
        //             
        //     TotalTimeString = null;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List < NameValuePair > params = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Global.userEmail));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", TotalTimeString));
            //Parameters for Update
            //                  List<NameValuePair> paramsUpdate = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //                  paramsUpdate.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Global.userEmail));
            //        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
            TIME_URL, "POST", params);
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Updated! Now gathering info for refresh!", json.toString());
                //                      JSONObject jsonRefresh = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                //                              UPDATE_URL, "POST", paramsUpdate);
                //                      if(success == 2){
                //                          Global.userTime = jsonRefresh.getDouble(TAG_TIME);
                //                          System.out.println(Global.userTime);
                //                          Log.d("Update Successful!", jsonRefresh.toString());
                //                      }
                //  Intent i = new Intent(Info.this, Info.class);
                finish();
                //  startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Info.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sorry for the mess, was going to clean it up when it was working.. ;)

EDIT: 
It now updates the database, but it still can't read the return. Someone mentioned earlier that the PHP was returning the html.. The database issue was just a matter of moving a line above another.. Could someone explain the issue with the PHP returning HTML, if that is true?

Comment: Post your java code creating the JSON object

Comment: Added the Android code. :)

Comment: When posting code, only post what's relevant. Your `import` statements, all the `View` initializations, etc. doesn't seem very relevant.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the JSON and checking it on jsonlint or some other service that verifies correct JSON output?

Comment: @mttdbrd Tried it, but this is my first dab with JSON, so I am not sure how it exactly works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSON.stringify()` to make it works .

Comment: The data that is being returned isn't even correct. Something is wrong in the PHP I believe, it should return "success":1.

Comment: Also, when you go to the web form and do it manually, it does print the {"success":1}, but the java code doesn't read it.. That is why I believe it is not even entering the info into the form.